# Is there any reliable way of accessing specific elements of Gmail from inside a userscript?

Tags: gmail, greasemonkey, css-selectors, userscripts

I'd like to make a script that replaces either the Notes box in the contact page, or the sidebar of a conversation thread, with content pulled from my server, very similar to the way Rapportive (http://rapportive.com/) works. I'd even like to be able to grab the email address of the person being looked at or emailed with, the way they do.

But Rapportive uses a browser extension. Is there any way this can be done via a greasemonkey script?

Is this something I should use a gadget for? Can I get the email address of the current 'context' from inside a gadget?

Comment: I am interested in something similar. Did you get ahead with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Still no, but I needed enough length to submit.